# Combine two ecto queries on the same schema into one with subquery or join

Tags: sql, postgresql, elixir, ecto

I have a `Post` schema with the virtual field `children` that I currently am populating by running a second query after first getting my `Post`.

Initial query to get the `Post`:

```
post = Post |> Repo.get(id)
```

then I run a second query to get its children and update the virtual `children` field:

```
children_query =
    from(p in Post,
      where: fragment("hierarchy <@ ?", ^post.hierarchy),
      order_by: p.inserted_at
    )

children = Repo.all(children_query)
post = Map.merge(post, %{children: children})
```

The hierarchy field is stored as an [Ltree](https://hostiledeveloper.com/2017/06/17/ltrees-in-phoenix.html) in the db and has the type of `:string` in the schema.

Is there any way that I could combine these queries into one? I tried to work with the Ecto [subquery/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#subquery/2) function but haven't been able to grok it.

I tried this but couldn't figure out how to pass the `Post` (p in this case) into the children subquery without getting the error that `the variable p is undefined` on the join line.

```
  def children_query(post) do
    from p in Post,
    where: fragment("hierarchy <@ ?", ^post.hierarchy),
    order_by: v.inserted_at
  end

  def get_post(p_id) do
    from(p in Post, 
    where: p.id == ^p_id,
    join: c in subquery(children_query(p)),
    on: p.id == c.id, # not sure how it would join on
    select: %{p | children: c}
    )
  end
```

I want to figure this out because it becomes very inefficient when showing the `Post` index page and having to run an additional children query for every post that is listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the subquery cannot be parametrized that way because it’s to be executed *before* the main query. One could move both conditions to be in the main query.

```
children = 
  from(p in Post,
       join: s in subquery(from p in Post),
       where: p.id == ^p_id and fragment("? <@ ?", s.hierarchy, p.hierarchy),
       select: [s, p])
```

The above produces a bit redundant result with `Post` glued to each of its children, but I did not manage to make it better.

Now you only need to split the result.

```
{post, children} =
  case Repo.all(children) do
    [[_, post] | _] = result -> {post, Enum.map(result, &hd/1)}
    [] -> {Repo.get(Post, p_id), []}
  end
```

The latter query is needed since when there are no children, the join returns an empty set.

Comment: why do you say "but I did not manage to make it better"? If I can get them combined into one query and not hit the db twice isn't that better than running two separate queries?

Comment: It is surely better than running 2 queries, I meant I did not manage to return the main post only once.

Comment: should `[{_, post} | _]` be [[_, post] | _] instead?

Comment: Yes, indeed, fixed.